# Tetris game, not getting fulfiled lines removed correctly

Tags: python, tetris

iam new to python and iam making tetris game, but my fulfiled lines are not removed correctly. When i fulfil just one or two lines in bottom, it works fine, but when i fulfil maybe 5 or more at once, it gets broken and lines are not removed anymore.

This my function function:

```
def check_line(shapes):
        my_arr = []
        count_dict = {}
        finished_arr = []

        for shape in shapes:
            for rect in shape:
                
                row = int(rect.y)
                my_arr.append(row)
        
        for y in my_arr:
            if y not in count_dict:
                count_dict[y] = 1
            else:
                count_dict[y] += 1

        
        most_common_nums = [k for k, v in count_dict.items() if v == 10]
        
        for one in most_common_nums:
            
            finished_arr.append(one)
        print(count_dict)
        
            
                
        return finished_arr
```

Iam printing count_dict and when are a lot of lines at once getting removed, it is printing {765: 11, 720: 12, 675: 9, 630: 8, 585: 6, 540: 2, 45: 2, 90: 2}.. i dont know how it counts 12 or 11 rectangles in one line.

And this is my implementation to loop:

```
if event.type == MOVE_SHAPE:
                
                
                
                
                collides_with_grid = any(shape.y >= (H*TILE) - TILE for shape in shapes[shape_num])
                collides_with_shape = False
                
                for rect in shapes[shape_num]:
                    for i in range(shape_num):
                        for rect2 in shapes[i]:
                        
                            if collides_shapes(rect, rect2):
                                collides_with_shape = True

                
                if collides_with_grid or collides_with_shape:
                    
                    if check_game_over(shapes):
                        
                        
                        game_over = True
                        if game_over:
                            current_speed = 0

                        else:
                            current_speed = speed

                        font_over = pygame.font.SysFont("calibri", 80, bold=True)
        
                        text2 = font_over.render("GAME OVER", True, "white")
                        text2_rect = text2.get_rect()
                        text2_rect.midtop =  220, 350
                        
                            
                        
                    
                    fulfilled_lines = check_line(shapes)
                    current_score += score_plus(len(fulfilled_lines))
                    text_score = font.render(f"SCORE: {current_score}", True, "white")
                    
                    
                    

                    
                    if len(fulfilled_lines) > 0:
                        if music:
                            music_coll.play()

                        
                        
                        for shape in shapes:
                            new_shapes = []
                            for rect in shape:
                                if rect.y not in fulfilled_lines:
                                    new_shapes.append(rect)

                            shape.clear()
                            shape.extend(new_shapes)
                        

                        
                            
                                    
                    
                        for shape in shapes:
                            for rect in shape:
                                for line in fulfilled_lines:
                                    if rect.y < line:
                                        rect.y += (len(fulfilled_lines) * TILE)


                    add_shape()
                    
                    shape_num += 1  
                        
                    
                    for shape in shapes[shape_num]:
                        grid.append(shape)       
                    

                else:
                    for shape in shapes[shape_num]:
                        shape.y += TILE
```

Thanks for help